# How to execute some code after changing state with NGRX?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I'm developing an app with Angular 2.0 and NGRX. I've come from React/Redux, so I'm still figuring out how to do some things.

When I want to print something inside the template I can write something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  directives: [MainContainer],
  styleUrls: [
    './dashboard.style.css'
  ],
  template: `
    <main-container [section]="viewSection | async"></main-container>
  `
})
export class Dashboard {

  private viewSection: Observable<MainViewSection>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
    this.viewSection = this.store.let(getMainViewSection());
  }

}
```

But now I want to execute some code after a value changes (it will use store's values as an input (that will change the view afterwards)

I know that I can do it with `componentWillReceiveProps` in React.

The only thing that I've found that can be usefull is something like this:

```
export class View {

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
    this.store.select('data').subscribe((val: DataState) => {
      if (!layer) {
        return;
      }
      layer.setData(val);
    });
  }

}
```

I don't think that's an elegant way, but I cannot figure out another way.. People has told me to use services (I don't know how that fits on this case) and I've read about `@Effects`, but I don't know if it's what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think `@Effect` is definitely what you are looking for. An `@Effect` executes when a certain state action gets called. Take this example from the official NgRx [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/effects/book.ts)

```
  @Effect() clearSearch$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(BookActions.SEARCH)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .filter(query => query === '')
    .mapTo(this.bookActions.searchComplete([]));
```

Using the `whenAction` method you specify which action triggers the effect. In this example they use `toPayload` which returns only the payload of the executed action. But you have access to the entire state of the application.

This is how you could use it for example:

```
    .whenAction(YourActions.SOMETHING)
    .switchMap(data => this._xhr.send(data.state.yourData)
```

Comment: I thought about it, but how can I trigger an object's method that's inside a component?
I have a map's layer that I have to change some parameters and call a method. Should I store the layer inside the state and change it through effects?

Comment: Yes i think so. If you want to call a method in a component when the state changes then it shouldn't really be a component method but rather a state action.